# Setting client area size (after creation)?

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi

I want to adjust the height of the client area *after* creation of the main window. I use `CW_USEDEFAULT` when creating it and I simply want to resize that to the nearest height which is divisible by a fixed number. I've tried processing `WM_SIZE`, but it doesn't seem to work like I want it to, and I'm not really sure `SetWindowPos` is the appropriate way to resize the *client* area.. ?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK mainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) {
      case WM_SIZE:
        if (HIWORD(lParam) % 15) {
          SetWindowPos(hWnd, NULL, 0, 0, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam) / 15 * 15, SWP_NOMOVE);
        }
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;

      case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

      default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result is a zero-height client area for some reason:

[image: Test]

Another couple of approaches I've tried:

- Updating the `RECT` *top* / *bottom* members when
  `WM_NCCALCSIZE` is sent.
- Changing the `cy` member of the `CREATESTRUCT` when the `WM_CREATE`
  message is sent.

Any ideas?

Comment: need call `return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam)` instead `return 0`

Comment: @RbMm getting the same result..

Comment: Use `SetWindowPos`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie that's what I'm doing currently?

Comment: Am I missing something? CreateWindow has paramers for x, y, nWidth, and nHeight. Stop using CW_USEDEFAULT and pick the values you want.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me. If you want to size your window so that the client area has a specific size, call [AdjustWindowRectEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632667.aspx) before constructing the window.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following, but not from the WM_SIZE message, just from a function:

```
r= <a rect with the size you want>;
/* Compute the size of the window rectangle based on the given
 * client rectangle size and the window style, then size the
 * client window.
 */
AdjustWindowRect (&r, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE), FALSE);
SetWindowPos (hWnd, 0,
          r.left, r.top,
          r.right  - r.left,
          r.bottom - r.top,
          SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

UpdateWindow(hWnd);
```

Comment: This doesn't work if your thread is DPI aware. You should use AdjustWindowRectExForDpi instead.

Comment: The function `AdjustWindowRectExForDpi` is available from Windows 10 1607 and is intended for developing "desktop applications to handle display scale factor (DPI) changes dynamically, allowing their applications to be crisp on any display they're rendered on."

Answer (score 0):

I realized my if-statement wasn't working as intended, since, when `SetWindowPos` is used to update the *main* window, it actually sets the *full window* height, whereas `HIWORD(lParam)` is only the *client area* height. In my case (Windows 7), the client area and full window height simply aren't *both* divisible by 15 at any point, so it will essentially keep looping. So here's my solution:

```
int initSize = 0; /* global */

/* ... */

case WM_SIZE:
    if (!initSize && HIWORD(lParam) % 15) {
        RECT r;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &r);
        r.bottom = r.top + (HIWORD(lParam) / 15 * 15);
        AdjustWindowRect(&r, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE), TRUE);
        SetWindowPos(hWnd, NULL, 0, 0, r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top, SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_NOACTIVATE|SWP_NOMOVE);
        initSize = 1;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    break;
```